# iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `auto' to `utf-8//IGNORE' is not allowed

Tags: php, utf-8, laravel-4, centos, dompdf

I am using the **thujohn/PDF-l4** plugin for my Laravel 4 framework. It works fine in local Windows environment. But when moved to my Centos production environment, the following error throws up for PDF conversion.

```
"iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `auto' to `utf-8//IGNORE' is not allowed"
```

Checked my php-mbstring, but couldn't find anything wrong.

Comment: In which library is the error originating? From what I've seen on the web that error indicates that the target encoding couldn't be found. Either utf8 isn't available on your server (seems unlikely) or the encoding string isn't matching up (maybe "UTF8"?)

Comment: @BrianS thanks for the comment the problem lied with the mbstring, which was fixed thanks anyway.......

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you post your fix?

Comment: @Benubird I used this meta tag in the export view template "<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">". This fixed the issue.......

Comment: I realise this is a very old post, but in my own researches for a different problem (people apparently mistyping ISO-8859-1 as ISO-8858-1, if you're interested), iconv shows this error message if either encoding specified does not exist (ISO-8858-1 doesn't). Of course, there may be many other circumstances which iconv also shows this error, just sharing what I found. On Linux, iconv -l in a shell shows what character sets are supported.

Comment: This comment saved me today 

Answer (score 7):

please install PHP mbstring and xml extensions on CentOS

Comment: Meta tag was causing the issue actually and fixed it. I checked on the mbstring and extensions at the start. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: how do you mean "meta tag" ?? how did you fix the issue ?